# Selecting entries with a specific year and month from a Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I select all database entries with a given date and month in a datetime? I tried this:

```
scope :with_year_and_month, ->(year, month) {
  where("YEAR(created_at) = ? AND MONTH(created_at) = ?", month, year)
}
```

Now that would work perfectly fine in a MySQL database, but in an Sqlite database it fails because Sqlite hasn't implemented the `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions. The following works fine though in Sqlite:

```
scope :with_year_and_month, ->(year, month) {
  where("strftime('%m', created_at) = ? AND strftime('%Y', created_at) = ?", "%02d" % month, year.to_s)
}
```

How would I do this in a database agnostic way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should let active record handle this, since it checks what database it's using and uses a driver for each database, the trick is to find a generic query to run, for me this is what I could come up with, might not be the best but I'm open for suggestions

```
scope :with_year_and_month, ->(year, month) {
  where(created_at: Date.new(year,month,1)..Date.new(year,month,-1))
}
```

This will generate a between query

```
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2015-02-28'
```

I think this should work with you

If created_at is `DateTime` then you should replace the `Date` with `DateTime` object so you don't miss the time between `2015-02-28 00:00:00` and `2015-02-28 23:59:59`, but you'll need extra parameters for the time

```
scope :with_year_and_month, ->(year, month) {
  where(created_at: DateTime.new(year,month,1)..DateTime.new(year,month,-1, -1, -1, -1))
}
```

of course you could create a small helper function to return those dates and shorten your method.
The result would be

```
Where created_at BETWEEN '2015-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-28 23:59:59'
```

**Update:**

So after a couple of comments, here's the final version

```
scope :with_year_and_month, ->(year, month) {
  date = DateTime.new(year,month)
  where(created_at: date...date.next_month)
}
```

The generated query would look like this

```
created_at >= '2015-02-01 00:00:00' AND created_at < '2015-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: I actually hadn't considered doing it this way. I changed the code slightly to make it a little more robust though: `d = DateTime.new(year, month).beginning_of_month; where(created_at: d..d.next_month)`. That way there's no chance of the last part of the month being excluded.

Comment: yea that would work, but just keep in mind that it would include the beginning of the first day, which is in my example `2015-03-01 00:00:00`, I know it's a very rare occasion, but keep it in mind.

Comment: Good point. Using `...` instead of `..` should fix that (by making the end of the range exclusive).

Comment: apparently there's also `end_of_month`, that would be good too, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: The problem with using `end_of_month` is it would exclude anything created during the very last second of the month, as `DATETIME` is stored with millisecond precision on the database. That's why I went with less-than the start of the next month.

Comment: hm, didn't know that, ok, i guess your way is more reliable, I'll edit again :D